# How to have a background extend indefinitely in the x direction

Tags: html, css, background, repeat

I have a header right now with a grey background that has a width of 100% and a max width of 1000px. I have a separate div with absolute position behind my actual header div that is currently the grey background so that the grey can extend beyond the 1000px limit. I want this grey background to extend as large as the screen goes, and it is currently doing that but the issue I am having is that because width is at 100% if a user has to scroll at all the grey background only is as wide as the browser, so I am left with a white background elsewhere. Is there something that I can do so that this is the full width of the screen, even with horizontal scrolling?

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mb1brnma/1/

The content within the fiddle is a little jumbled, but it does represent the problem where if you scroll right the background does not extend fully to the right.

Edit:

HTML:

```
    <div id="footerTopBG"></div>
    <div id="footerBG"></div>

<body>
<div id="footer-container">
    <div id="footer-holder">
        <footer>  
            <section id="mid">
                <div align=left class="box">
                    <h5>Customer Care</h5>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/pages/Return-Policy.html">Return Policy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/free-shipping.html">Free Shipping*</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/pages/Terms-And-Conditions.html">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/pages/Privacy-Statement.html">Privacy Statement</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/pages/FCC-Wireless-Alert.html">FCC Wireless Alert</a></li>
                    </ul>
</div>
                <div align=left class="box">
                        <h5>More About NLFX</h5>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/pages/About-us.html">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://gobos.nlfxpro.com">NLFX Pro Custom Gobo</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/pages/Installations.html">Installations</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/pages/Blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                        </ul>
</div>
                <div align=left class="box">
                      <FM>
                        <h5>Follow NLFX</h5>
                        <ul id="A">
                            <li class="one"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/nlfxpro/"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                            <li class="two"><a href="https://twitter.com/NLfxPro?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li></ul>
                          <ul id="B">
                            <li class="one"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/NLFXProfessional?feature=sub_widget_1"><i class="fa fa-youtube-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                            <li class="two"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/nlfxpro/?hl=en"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </FM>
</div>
                <div align=left class="box">
                      <div id="af-form-2011966506" class="af-form"><div id="af-header-2011966506" class="af-header"><div class="bodyText"><p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 18px;white-space=nowrap;"><strong style="color: whitesmoke;">Newsletter signup!</strong></span></p></div></div><div id="af-body-2011966506" class="af-body af-standards"><div class="af-element"><div class="af-textWrap"><input id="awf_field-79641788" type="text" name="name" class="text" value="" onfocus=" if (this.value == '') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='';} " tabindex="500" placeholder="Your Name"></div><div class="af-clear"></div></div><div class="af-element"><div class="af-textWrap"><input class="text" id="awf_field-79641789" type="text" name="email" value="" tabindex="501" onfocus=" if (this.value == '') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='';} " placeholder="Email Address"></div><div class="af-clear"></div></div><div class="af-element"><div class="af-selectWrap"><select id="awf_field-79641790" name="custom Your Interests" tabindex="502"> <option selected="selected" class="multiChoice" value="">Select an Interest</option><option class="multiChoice" value="Dj">DJ</option><option class="multiChoice" value="House of worship">House of Worship</option><option class="multiChoice" value="Family fun center">Family Fun Center</option><option class="multiChoice" value="Live Production">Live Production</option><option class="multiChoice" value="Performance venue">Performance Venue</option><option class="multiChoice" value="Rental company">Rental Company</option></select></div><input type="hidden" name="meta_preselected_awf_field-79641790" value="---select one---"><div class="af-clear"></div></div><div class="af-element buttonContainer"><input name="submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="     Subscribe to our Newsletter!     " tabindex="503"><div class="af-clear"></div></div></div></div>
</div>
            </section>            
            <section id="bottom">
                <address>
                    <p class="big">NLFX Professional</p>
                    <p>1319 Naylor Drive SE</p>
                    <p>Bemidji, MN 56601</p>
                    <p><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/NLFX+Professional/@47.4419595,-94.8508662,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x52b82dc7d2024257:0xd700f2707b61b267!8m2!3d47.4419559!4d-94.8486775" target="_blank">View Map</a></p>
                </address>
                <div class="phone">
                    <p class="big">Contact Us</p>
                    <p>Toll Free: 1-888-660-6696</p>
                    <p>Local: 218-444-2994</p>
                    <p>Email: <a href="mailto:customercare@nlfxpro.com">customercare@nlfxpro.com</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="hours">
                    <p class="big">Store Hours</p>
                    <p>Monday - Friday</p>
                    <p>8:30am - 5:00pm</p>
                </div>
                <div class="copy">
                    Copyright &copy; 2012 NLFX Professional 
                </div>
            </section>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
    footer {
    width: 100%;
    max-width:900px;
    min-width:770px;
    float: left;
    height:310px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #9b9b9b 61.2%,#414141 61.2%); 
}

footer #mid {
    width: 96%;
    margin: 2%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    max-width:900px;
    min-width:720px;
}

footer #mid .box {
    width: 25%;
    overflow: visible;
    float: left;
}

footer #mid .box h5 {
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

footer #mid .box ul {
    width: 170px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

footer #mid .box ul li a{
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

footer #mid .box FM li a{
    display:inline;
    font-size:23px;
    padding-top:0px !!important;
}

footer #mid .box FM li a:hover{
    font-size: 25px;
}

footer #mid .box FM .one{
    position: absolute;
    text-align: right;
    right:120px
}

footer #mid .box FM .two{
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    left:58px;
}

footer #mid .box FM #B{
    bottom:-30px;
}

footer #mid .box FM #A{
    bottom:-5px;
}

footer #mid .box FM #A li:hover{
    transform: translateY(-5px);
}

footer #mid .box ul li a:hover {
    color: #ccc;
    transform: translate(2%);
}

#af-form-2011966506{
    float: left;
    margin-left: -60px;
    padding:8px;
    overflow: visible;
    border:1px solid white;
}

#awf_field-79641790{
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 2.5px;
}

footer #bottom {
    width: 100%;
    max-width:900px;
    min-width:720px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    color: ghostwhite;
    margin: 10px 2%;
    display:inline;
}

footer #bottom address {
    width: 26%;
    margin-right: 50px;
    float: left;
    font-style: normal;
}

footer #bottom .big {
    color: whitesmoke;
    font-family: 'TeXGyreAdventor', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
}

footer #bottom address a {
    color:deepskyblue;
}

footer #bottom address a:hover {
    color:skyblue;
}

footer #bottom .phone {
    margin: 0;
    width: 30%;
    min-width: 230px;
    float: left;
}

footer #bottom .phone a {
    color: deepskyblue;
}

footer #bottom .phone a:hover {
    color: skyblue;
}

footer #bottom .hours {
    margin-left: 50px;
    float: left;
    width: 26%;
}

footer #bottom .copy {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
    color: whitesmoke;
    font-size: 12px;
}



#footerBG{
    background-color:#414141;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width: 100%;
    min-width:700px;
    position:relative;
    height: 120px;
    z-index: -999999;
}

#footerTopBG{
    background-color:#9b9b9b;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width: 100%;
    min-width:700px;
    position:relative;
    margin-top: -310px;
    height: 190px;
    z-index: -9999;
}
```

Comment: provide code, please. Ideally a snippet with relevant html and css

Comment: @mikepa88 The code has been added. If this is not enough code I can add more, but this is everything for the footer I believe, which is where the problem is occuring.

Comment: I do not see a problem with that code *if I take out the `<body>` tag*. Is that actually how your code is – with `#footerBG` outside the `<body>` tag? If so, don't do that; move it inside, and see if it works. If not, then see if you can provide a stack snippet that reproduces the problem because some other issue must be in play.

Comment: @cjl750 That is how my code actually is. The problem that bringing it into the body is that then the `width 100%` attribute makes it only as wide as the body is, which is maxed out at 1000px. I want this to be the full width of the screen at all times.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147653/discussion-between-cjl750-and-jake-p).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so, working off your fiddle, we can see that the problem isn't that the background color doesn't stretch to 100% the width of the page, but rather that the elements in your footer add up to over 100%! So the only way to get the background color to truly take up the whole page is to either A.) provide some parent element that truly contains all its children, and giving that the background color instead; or, B.) set whatever it is that has the background color to be bigger than 100% of the page width (or at least stick out beyond the right bound of the page).

The first option below works around approach A; the second option is based around approach B; the third option is just bonus points. *Make sure to resize the screen on both of them to see how they compare at wide vs narrow screen sizes.*

To start, here are our problem styles:

```
footer {
  min-width: 770px;
}
footer #mid {
  min-width: 720px;
}
footer #bottom {
  min-width: 720px;
}
```

Also, you should not include any elements outside your `<body>` tag, besides the `<head>`. That is not valid HTML. But we do not actually need `<div id="footerTopBG">` or `<div id="footerBG">` in this case, so I have simply commented them out in the following examples (in addition to deleting the `body` and `html` tags you had, which are not necessary in a fiddle or in a stack snippet).

### Option 1: parent element scrolls

The first approach is to set the background color on the wrapper element, and make sure that element's `min-width` is wide enough to truly contain everything.

```
#footer-container {
  background-color: #9b9b9b;
  min-width: 900px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

You'll basically want to make that `min-width` value as small as possible, to prevent excess scrolling on small screens. The precise value will be determined by your font sizes and font faces, and the child elements' widths and margins and whatnot.

**Option one:**

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 900px;
  min-width: 770px;
  float: left;
  height: 310px;
}
footer #mid {
  width: 96%;
  margin: 2%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  max-width: 900px;
  min-width: 720px;
}
footer #mid .box {
  width: 25%;
  overflow: visible;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
footer #mid .box h5 {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 18px;
  /* position: absolute; */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
footer #mid .box ul {
  width: 170px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
footer #mid .box ul li a {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
footer #mid .box FM li a {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 23px;
  padding-top: 0px !important;
}
footer #mid .box FM li a:hover {
  font-size: 25px;
}
footer #mid .box FM .one {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  right: 120px
}
/* footer #mid .box FM .two {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  left: 58px;
} */
footer #mid .box FM #B {
  bottom: -30px;
}
footer #mid .box FM #A {
  bottom: -5px;
}
footer #mid .box FM #A li:hover {
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}
footer #mid .box ul li a:hover {
  color: #ccc;
  transform: translate(2%);
}
#af-form-2011966506 {
  float: left;
  margin-left: -60px;
  padding: 8px;
  /* overflow: visible; */
  border: 1px solid white;
}
#awf_field-79641790 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
}
footer #bottom {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 900px;
  min-width: 720px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  color: ghostwhite;
  margin: 10px 2%;
  display: inline;
}
footer #bottom address {
  width: 26%;
  margin-right: 50px;
  float: left;
  font-style: normal;
}
footer #bottom .big {
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-family: 'TeXGyreAdventor', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}
footer #bottom address a {
  color: deepskyblue;
}
footer #bottom address a:hover {
  color: skyblue;
}
footer #bottom .phone {
  margin: 0;
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 230px;
  float: left;
}
footer #bottom .phone a {
  color: deepskyblue;
}
footer #bottom .phone a:hover {
  color: skyblue;
}
footer #bottom .hours {
  margin-left: 50px;
  float: left;
  width: 26%;
}
footer #bottom .copy {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-size: 12px;
}
/* NEW */
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#footer-container {
  background-color: #9b9b9b;
  min-width: 900px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- <div id="footerTopBG"></div>
<div id="footerBG"></div> -->
<div id="footer-container">
  <div id="footer-holder">
    <footer>
      <section id="mid">
        <div align=left class="box">
          <h5>Customer Care</h5>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/pages/Return-Policy.html">Return Policy</a></li>
            <li><a href="/free-shipping.html">Free Shipping*</a></li>
            <li><a href="/pages/Terms-And-Conditions.html">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
            <li><a href="/pages/Privacy-Statement.html">Privacy Statement</a></li>
            <li><a href="/pages/FCC-Wireless-Alert.html">FCC Wireless Alert</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div align=left class="box">
          <h5>More About NLFX</h5>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/pages/About-us.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://gobos.nlfxpro.com">NLFX Pro Custom Gobo</a></li>
            <li><a href="/pages/Installations.html">Installations</a></li>
            <li><a href="/pages/Blog.html">Blog</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div align=left class="box">
          <FM>
            <h5>Follow NLFX</h5>
            <ul id="A">
              <li class="one"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/nlfxpro/"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
              <li class="two"><a href="https://twitter.com/NLfxPro?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="B">
              <li class="one"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/NLFXProfessional?feature=sub_widget_1"><i class="fa fa-youtube-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
              <li class="two"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/nlfxpro/?hl=en"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
          </FM>
        </div>
        <div align=left class="box">
          <div id="af-form-2011966506" class="af-form">
            <div id="af-header-2011966506" class="af-header">
              <div class="bodyText">
                <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 18px;white-space=nowrap;"><strong style="color: whitesmoke;">Newsletter signup!</strong></span></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="af-body-2011966506" class="af-body af-standards">
              <div class="af-element">
                <div class="af-textWrap">
                  <input id="awf_field-79641788" type="text" name="name" class="text" value="" onfocus=" if (this.value == '') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='';} " tabindex="500" placeholder="Your Name">
                </div>
                <div class="af-clear"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="af-element">
                <div class="af-textWrap">
                  <input class="text" id="awf_field-79641789" type="text" name="email" value="" tabindex="501" onfocus=" if (this.value == '') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='';} " placeholder="Email Address">
                </div>
                <div class="af-clear"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="af-element">
                <div class="af-selectWrap">
                  <select id="awf_field-79641790" name="custom Your Interests" tabindex="502">
                    <option selected="selected" class="multiChoice" value="">Select an Interest</option>
                    <option class="multiChoice" value="Dj">DJ</option>
                    <option class="multiChoice" value="House of worship">House of Worship</option>
                    <option class="multiChoice" value="Family fun center">Family Fun Center</option>
                    <option class="multiChoice" value="Live Production">Live Production</option>
                    <option class="multiChoice" value="Performance venue">Performance Venue</option>
                    <option class="multiChoice" value="Rental company">Rental Company</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="meta_preselected_awf_field-79641790" value="---select one---">
                <div class="af-clear"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="af-element buttonContainer">
                <input name="submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="     Subscribe to our Newsletter!     " tabindex="503">
                <div class="af-clear"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section id="bottom">
        <address>
                    <p class="big">NLFX Professional</p>
                    <p>1319 Naylor Drive SE</p>
                    <p>Bemidji, MN 56601</p>
                    <p><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/NLFX+Professional/@47.4419595,-94.8508662,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x52b82dc7d2024257:0xd700f2707b61b267!8m2!3d47.4419559!4d-94.8486775" target="_blank">View Map</a></p>
                </address>
        <div class="phone">
          <p class="big">Contact Us</p>
          <p>Toll Free: 1-888-660-6696</p>
          <p>Local: 218-444-2994</p>
          <p>Email: <a href="mailto:customercare@nlfxpro.com">customercare@nlfxpro.com</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="hours">
          <p class="big">Store Hours</p>
          <p>Monday - Friday</p>
          <p>8:30am - 5:00pm</p>
        </div>
        <div class="copy">
          Copyright &copy; 2012 NLFX Professional
        </div>
      </section>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Option 2: pseudo element

The second way we can fix the problem is to find whatever the actual width of your content is and make a pseudo element to sit behind the footer that extends off to the right, past the typical right bound, so the background is basically more than 100% wide.

This will be easiest if you add the pseudo element to the biggest container you can, so I added it to `#footer-container`.

```
#footer-container {
  background-color: #9b9b9b;
}
#footer-container::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background-color: #9b9b9b;
  width: 793px;
  height: 492px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

That's about it. Just like in option one, the precise width of your pseudo element will depend on the the font and font size you have going on, the widths and margins/padding of other elements, and everything else.

The other things we have to do to make this work is to clearfix `#footer-holder` so that it will be tall enough to contain all its children, and then remove the explicit height off of `footer`.

**Option two:**

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 900px;
  min-width: 770px;
  float: left;
  /* height: 310px; */
}
footer #mid {
  width: 96%;
  margin: 2%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  max-width: 900px;
  min-width: 720px;
}
footer #mid .box {
  width: 25%;
  overflow: visible;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
footer #mid .box h5 {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 18px;
  /* position: absolute; */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
footer #mid .box ul {
  width: 170px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
footer #mid .box ul li a {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
footer #mid .box FM li a {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 23px;
  padding-top: 0px !important;
}
footer #mid .box FM li a:hover {
  font-size: 25px;
}
footer #mid .box FM .one {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  right: 120px
}
footer #mid .box FM .two {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  left: 58px;
}
footer #mid .box FM #B {
  bottom: -30px;
}
footer #mid .box FM #A {
  bottom: -5px;
}
footer #mid .box FM #A li:hover {
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}
footer #mid .box ul li a:hover {
  color: #ccc;
  transform: translate(2%);
}
#af-form-2011966506 {
  float: left;
  margin-left: -60px;
  padding: 8px;
  overflow: visible;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
#awf_field-79641790 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
}
footer #bottom {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 900px;
  min-width: 720px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  color: ghostwhite;
  margin: 10px 2%;
  display: inline;
}
footer #bottom address {
  width: 26%;
  margin-right: 50px;
  float: left;
  font-style: normal;
}
footer #bottom .big {
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-family: 'TeXGyreAdventor', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}
footer #bottom address a {
  color: deepskyblue;
}
footer #bottom address a:hover {
  color: skyblue;
}
footer #bottom .phone {
  margin: 0;
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 230px;
  float: left;
}
footer #bottom .phone a {
  color: deepskyblue;
}
footer #bottom .phone a:hover {
  color: skyblue;
}
footer #bottom .hours {
  margin-left: 50px;
  float: left;
  width: 26%;
}
footer #bottom .copy {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-size: 12px;
}
/* NEW */
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#footer-container {
  background-color: #9b9b9b;
}
#footer-container::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background-color: #9b9b9b;
  width: 793px;
  height: 492px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.clearfix::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!-- <div id="footerTopBG"></div>
<div id="footerBG"></div> -->
<div id="footer-container">
  <div id="footer-holder" class="clearfix">
    <footer>
      <section id="mid">
        <div align=left class="box">
          <h5>Customer Care</h5>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/pages/Return-Policy.html">Return Policy</a></li>
            <li><a href="/free-shipping.html">Free Shipping*</a></li>
            <li><a href="/pages/Terms-And-Conditions.html">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
            <li><a href="/pages/Privacy-Statement.html">Privacy Statement</a></li>
            <li><a href="/pages/FCC-Wireless-Alert.html">FCC Wireless Alert</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div align=left class="box">
          <h5>More About NLFX</h5>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/pages/About-us.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://gobos.nlfxpro.com">NLFX Pro Custom Gobo</a></li>
            <li><a href="/pages/Installations.html">Installations</a></li>
            <li><a href="/pages/Blog.html">Blog</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div align=left class="box">
          <FM>
            <h5>Follow NLFX</h5>
            <ul id="A">
              <li class="one"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/nlfxpro/"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
              <li class="two"><a href="https://twitter.com/NLfxPro?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="B">
              <li class="one"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/NLFXProfessional?feature=sub_widget_1"><i class="fa fa-youtube-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
              <li class="two"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/nlfxpro/?hl=en"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
          </FM>
        </div>
        <div align=left class="box">
          <div id="af-form-2011966506" class="af-form">
            <div id="af-header-2011966506" class="af-header">
              <div class="bodyText">
                <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 18px;white-space=nowrap;"><strong style="color: whitesmoke;">Newsletter signup!</strong></span></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="af-body-2011966506" class="af-body af-standards">
              <div class="af-element">
                <div class="af-textWrap">
                  <input id="awf_field-79641788" type="text" name="name" class="text" value="" onfocus=" if (this.value == '') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='';} " tabindex="500" placeholder="Your Name">
                </div>
                <div class="af-clear"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="af-element">
                <div class="af-textWrap">
                  <input class="text" id="awf_field-79641789" type="text" name="email" value="" tabindex="501" onfocus=" if (this.value == '') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='';} " placeholder="Email Address">
                </div>
                <div class="af-clear"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="af-element">
                <div class="af-selectWrap">
                  <select id="awf_field-79641790" name="custom Your Interests" tabindex="502">
                    <option selected="selected" class="multiChoice" value="">Select an Interest</option>
                    <option class="multiChoice" value="Dj">DJ</option>
                    <option class="multiChoice" value="House of worship">House of Worship</option>
                    <option class="multiChoice" value="Family fun center">Family Fun Center</option>
                    <option class="multiChoice" value="Live Production">Live Production</option>
                    <option class="multiChoice" value="Performance venue">Performance Venue</option>
                    <option class="multiChoice" value="Rental company">Rental Company</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="meta_preselected_awf_field-79641790" value="---select one---">
                <div class="af-clear"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="af-element buttonContainer">
                <input name="submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="     Subscribe to our Newsletter!     " tabindex="503">
                <div class="af-clear"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section id="bottom">
        <address>
                    <p class="big">NLFX Professional</p>
                    <p>1319 Naylor Drive SE</p>
                    <p>Bemidji, MN 56601</p>
                    <p><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/NLFX+Professional/@47.4419595,-94.8508662,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x52b82dc7d2024257:0xd700f2707b61b267!8m2!3d47.4419559!4d-94.8486775" target="_blank">View Map</a></p>
                </address>
        <div class="phone">
          <p class="big">Contact Us</p>
          <p>Toll Free: 1-888-660-6696</p>
          <p>Local: 218-444-2994</p>
          <p>Email: <a href="mailto:customercare@nlfxpro.com">customercare@nlfxpro.com</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="hours">
          <p class="big">Store Hours</p>
          <p>Monday - Friday</p>
          <p>8:30am - 5:00pm</p>
        </div>
        <div class="copy">
          Copyright &copy; 2012 NLFX Professional
        </div>
      </section>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Option 3: responsive design

As I see it, the *symptom* is that your background color doesn't extend all the way to the right, but the underlying *problem* is that the footer isn't responsive – it doesn't fit within the browser window.

To fix this problem, you have to basically adjust your styles to get rid of a lot of the minimum widths and remove a lot of the unnecessary positioning and overflow rules so that everything just flows as normal in a small space. Then you just give the footer the background color, and you're good to go because you won't need to scroll right.

I'll leave it to you to decide if this is really what you want to do or not, but figured I'd leave it as an option.

This approach basically amounts to removing many styles related to positioning and overflow and then adding in a media query to adjust some styles. Here's the essentials:

```
footer {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 900px;
  /* min-width: 770px; */
  /* float: left; */
  /* height: 310px; */
}
footer #mid {
  width: 96%;
  margin: 2%;
  max-width: 900px;
  /* float: left; */
  /* position: relative; */
  /* display: inline; */
  /* min-width: 720px; */
}
footer #mid .box {
  /* width: 25%; */
  /* overflow: visible; */
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
#footer-container {
  background-color: #9b9b9b;
}
@media all and (max-width: 620px) {
  footer #mid .box:nth-child(odd) {
    clear: left;
  }  
  footer #mid .box {
    width: 48%; /* 96% width of #mid, divided by 2 */
  }
}
```

Note that there's probably other styles you could remove to simplify things further, and those are not the only styles I commented out in the snippet below, but that should illustrate the concept.

The result is still a bit ugly with random bullets floating around and whatnot, but I assume that you will rectify those issues on your actual site.

Since I'm running out of characters on this post, [here's a fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/mb1brnma/13/) for you to look at.

Comment: Option two looks like it will work best for me. The one issue that I am still having is that with this option (and with option one) the background color is still being contained to the 900px limit. I do not want my content being wider than 1000px, but I want the color to extend beyond that.

Comment: Try adjusting the positioning a bit. You could change `left: 0` to `right: ??` and fill in the question marks. And remember you may have to adjust the width for your specific case as well. I recommend inspecting the element in your browser's console (in Chrome, right-click > inspect), and change the width and positioning in there to figure out what numbers are exactly correct. Then, update your CSS file.

Comment: After messing with that I was able to have it extend beyond the 1000px. This has now caused a different issue though, in order for it to still show the background I have to extend the width beyond 100% as you said. If I do this then the website treats that as content and will let me scroll right even if there is nothing but grey there. That is the only problem remaining.

Comment: Yes, that is the whole part I did not fully understand in the first place. Ideally, the site would not scroll sideways anyway. But if you don't want to go to full responsive route to fix that issue, then I recommend simply finding the smallest amount you can make the pseudo element while still covering everything, and going with that. You could also use media queries to only add the pseudo element (and thus cause scrolling) at smaller screen sizes, if applicable. Or use `body { overflow-x: hidden }` at large screen sizes to at least remove the scrollbar on desktop.